# Sharepoint 2013 - Pop-up window before sharing to everyone

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development, powershell

I'd like to warn users before sharing a file or a site to "Everyone" by showing a pop up.
Is there a way to do this ?

Otherwise, is there a way to block sharing to everyone ?

Thank you for your help.

---

Hi,

Any help please ?
I just need to get a prompt when people try to share.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to hide everyone in your people picker. Use the script below, there will be no everyone option in sharing(and any people picker)

```
$claimMgr = Get-SPClaimProviderManager

$allUser = get-spclaimprovider –identity "AllUsers"

$allUser.IsEnabled = $false

$claimMgr.Update()
```

[image]

And your can set it back by changing the $false to $true then run the script again.

Comment: Thank you Jerry_MSFT for your answer but I already have this script but is not a solution.
In fact, we still need "Everyone" to be pickable.